# jQuery getting all widths of a specific element in a specific element and sum them up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a function for my grid system to check if the `size` elements in the `row` their `width`s is more then `100%`, it hides the row.

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
                <div class="column size-1"><p>column-size-1</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
                <div class="column size-2"><p>column-size-2</p></div>
            </div>
```

In 1 row, can fit 12 columns. So a `size-1` class is `1 / 12` in percentage.

I have this piece of code and i have already achieved to get every width of each `size` element in one `row`. But only separately...

I want it to get every width of every `size` element wich it can find in every row, and sum those up.

Here is what my function currently looks like.

```
function check() {
    var size = '.row [class*="size-"]',
        _size = $(size);
    $(_size).each(function () {
        var widths = $(this).width(),
            inProcent = (widths) / $(this).parent().width() * 100;
            console.log(inProcent);
    });
}
```

**Wanted output:**

```
100%
100%
```

**Actual output:**

```
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
8.333333%
16.666667%
16.666667%
16.666667%
16.666667%
16.666667%
16.666667%
```

Comment: I recommend running the `each` twice; once for each row. Declare a variable outside the `each` and increment it inside the `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging the size for each element seperately, you still need to sum them up together.
Also you will want to do that seperately for each row.

```
function check() {
    var rows = $('.row');
    rows.each(function(i, e) { //here "this" is the row
        var columns = $(e).find('[class*="size-"]');
        var sum;
        columns.each(function (i, el) { //here "this" becomes the column.
            //If you want to access the row, you need the "e" variable!
            var width = $(el).width(), 
            inProcent = width / $(el).parent().width() * 100;
            sum += inProcent;
        }); 
        console.log(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah okay, but how would i do that then?:C

Comment: Thanks, it worked :D but what are those `i, e` arguments from the functions? :S

Comment: @Dreiba those stand for `index` and `element`, [as passed by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Index is the index in the collection, element is the element itself and is the same as `each`. You wrap it into a jQuery object again by doing `$(e)` so the jQuery functions are available on it. By the way, don't forget to upvote if my answer was helpful ;)

Comment: just did :) and thanks :D is it more efficient then using `$(this)` then? Or isnt it the same?

Comment: @Dreiba `this` is a global variable that is available to anything, `e` is a local variable that is only available within the `each` function. In fact the reason to use `e` and `el` here (see updated code) is that in the second `each` loop, by `this` you can only access the column element. But now you can still access the row element with the `e` variable ;) I hope you understand!

Comment: ah thanks man, didnt know. Btw, maybe its a little bit besides the point. But i also got margins on every `.column` class, How can i add those to the calculation?

Comment: @Dreiba Replace `width()` with `outerWidth(true)`. See: http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: thank you, i wonder why i get on the first one a total width of `99.98029427220177` tho. When i have 12 columns. Can i round it up to 100%? sorry for my bad english btw

Comment: @Dreiba that is because floating point values are not 100% accurate in programming languages due to the binary nature of computers. The more calculations with floating points, the more deviation you will end up with. It's best to only round your final result though. But don't assume this gains you accuracy. If you need more accurate floating point numbers, other solutions are available. For now, you can use `Math.round(sum)`.